# How to add Ubuntu One icon as an indicator?

Tags: ubuntu-one, indicator

I have Precise. I don't like that Ubuntu One's icon is located in the notifications area under the envelope. I would like the cloud icon back on the panel like it used to be. Is there a way to do this? I have searched and it seems no one has asked this question.

Comment: UbuntuOne use OSD notifies for that. I tried many icon themes but the only thing I got is an offline/online status.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Ubuntu One indicator.

To install the indicator, run these commands in a terminal:

**12.04**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-ubuntuone
```

**11.10 and earlier**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-indicator
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet-adds-new-features/

Comment: Did not work for me (11.10)

Comment: I would expect something more descriptive than "Did not work for me" so I can at least try to solve your problem.

Comment: ok... I ran the two command indicated for 11.10  They completed successfully and then nothing happened.  The indicator didn't appear but I also didn't get any error message.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Can you check if it is added to your startup applications? I guess it is not starting when you login and hence you can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

This applet seems to be what you are looking for.
[Launchpad: Ubuntu One Indicator Plugin](https://launchpad.net/indicator-ubuntuone)
It applet lets you open your UbuntuOne folder, launch the website, monitor up- and download status, connect and disconnect to U1. It also displays a nice cloud icon indicating whether syncing is going on or not.

[image: indicator-ubuntuone screenshot]

Here is an old article on [Webupd8: Ubuntu One Indicator Applet](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet.html), and a newer one [Omg!Ubuntu!: Ubuntu One Indicator Applet Adds New Features](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet-adds-new-features/) (includes a how to install with PPA and download links).

The applets PPA is [ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras](https://launchpad.net/~rye/+archive/ubuntuone-extras), the package is called "indicator-ubuntuone".

Comment: This looked great and I was able to add the software source.  However it did not fix the issue at all for me (v11.10)  I also tried http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet.html which looked promising but did not work for my 11.10 system.

Comment: regret to but I am downvoting as this didn't work for me.

Comment: According to the PPA page "the Indicator package was renamed to indicator-ubuntuone" "starting from 12.04", did you try to install _indicator-ubuntuone_ or _ubuntuone-indicator_? Maybe downloading _indicator-ubuntuone_ and installing it regardless of your Ubuntu version from https://launchpad.net/~rye/+archive/ubuntuone-extras/+packages works for you, as the PPA for 11.10 seems to contain quite an old version.

Answer (score 1):

I did more research.  Looks like "not yet".

Article isn't dated but is what displays as of today  - 5/18/2012
https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/are-there-notifications/