# Is there any way to get an indicator for Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add Ubuntu One icon as an indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131822/how-to-add-ubuntu-one-icon-as-an-indicator)

I would like to see an icon so that I know if Ubuntu One uploads/downloads are going on.
Haven't found it yet.

[EDIT] I tried the answers given and although able to add the software source, was not able to get the indicator going.  Tried for a couple hours then gave up.

My issues may be specific to 11.10.