#  how can I get the UbuntuOne panel icon starting in the background via my .bashrc

Tags: 11.10, indicator, ubuntu-one, panel, background-process

Trying to get an indicator working to show UbuntuOne progress, like the Dropbox one.

This helped: [Is there any way to get an indicator for Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138984/is-there-any-way-to-get-an-indicator-for-ubuntu-one/138988#138988)
Also this http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet.html actually gave me the command to run -

```
/usr/bin/ubuntuone-indicator
```

However this ties up the terminal so I want to run it in the background and ideally have it in my .bashrc to start on startup.

However when I try `/usr/bin/ubuntuone-indicator &` the indicator comes up... but the terminal is tied up and doesn't return the command prompt.

I can interrupt it (ctrl-c) and the indicator actually stays, so it seems like the job was actually in the background.  Stopping it at this point requires a `kill` command.

So how can i get this working in the background ok so that I can add it to my .bashrc shell?

At the command line:

If I try `/usr/bin/ubuntuone-indicator` it starts, but the terminal is hung and indicator gets killed with a ctrl-c

If I try `/usr/bin/ubuntuone-indicator &` it starts the icon indicator but still hangs the terminal.  If I ctrl-c, that works (exits) and the process is left in the background (requires kill to stop it).  This is good... except that I can't "ctrl-c" for the .bashrc script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the application with nohup

```
nohup /usr/bin/ubuntuone-indicator &
```

You should now be able to close the terminal.

Assuming that works, IMO, you want to add that command do a script which then runs at login rather then adding it to `.bashrc`

Add your script or command to `Startup applications`

[image: startup applications]

Comment: Yes, I added `/usr/bin/ubuntuone-indicator` to the bottom of `/etc/init.d/rc.local`  This worked.

Comment: `rc.local` is also the wrong place to run the script: you want to run the indicator as part of the desktop login session rather than on boot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to stat it from .bashrc

That file is executed whenever you start a terminal, so if you start 5 of them, you will start 5 indicators.